# Axios send get form data empty?

Tags: axios

I make an axios request in postman when I check form-data
[image]

How can send the same check form-data on axios.get()

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get(URL, { params: { fields: ["id"] }})
```

If you want to send it as actual form-data/body then axios does not support it. It only supports form-data/body when the method is `PUT`, `POST` and `PATCH`.

Any reason for having a get expecting form data?